# Where does Eclipse install itself? - to_do

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (includes Incubating components)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you downloaded is the application itself. It does not have an installer so just copy the folder you extracted to wherever you want. To uninstall it just delete the folder.

Comment: It's just the way they decided to arrange it. It is a plugin architecture so most of the binaries (JARs) are in the plugins folder.

Comment: I didn't know you were looking for that... beats me. You shouldn't need to find that to debug though. You can just run a Debug from inside eclipse: Right click project > Debug As > C++ app

Comment: @stack.user.1: When you install Eclipse CDT you install the IDE, but not the tool chain. You have to download and install the tool chain (compiler+linker+debugger...) separately. If your tool chain is installed but Eclipse has not detected it, you can configure it (somewhere I don't remember, it's been quite long since I have had to do that)

Comment: Sorry yes I forgot. I use Ubuntu and just install the toolchain via synaptic.

Answer (score 1):

Time marches on! I just downloaded the latest (Neon) for Android for Mac and it downloaded an installer, which installed it to /Users/Willy/eclipse/android-neon by default. Super-smooth install!

Comment: I don't know about macs, but for Windows that's a terrible install path.  Everything should go under Program Files or Program files (x86)